# CTE Issues for Selecting Distinct Values and assigned NEWID() to those values

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, newid

I'm having an issue with some CTE code I'm working with.  My current goal is that I have a table that has a 'Type' column.  I want to select all the DISTINCT types from that 'Type' column and, for each type, assign a value of NEWID() to a separate column.

Heres a sample table that im starting with:

| Type | NEW ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL |
| 4 | NULL |
| 4 | NULL |
| 4 | NULL |
| MA | NULL |
| MA | NULL |

```
    WITH unique_gen_id AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT type, NEWID() AS unique_id
        FROM tmp
        )

    UPDATE t
    SET t.unique_id = u.unique_id
    FROM tmp t  INNER JOIN
    unique_gen_id u ON t.type = u.type
```

This query almost works-- it assigns a "NEWID()" unique value to each respective "Type" with a few mishaps.  (Type is not specific to either an int or character, could be anything).

| Type | NEW ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B280347A-C394-4656 |
| 1 | B280347A-C394-4656 |
| 4 | C03F0E24-7187-4CC2 |
| 4 | D10415A8-55BD-4251 |
| 4 | D10415A8-55BD-4251 |
| MA | DBE92CA0-B440-484D |
| MA | DBE92CA0-B440-484D |

As you can see, the query returned almost fine. It failed, however, with "Type" of '4' as it assigned 2 separate 'NEWIDS()' when its supposed to match all the way through.

It gets worse with different data-- I tried on different data using different 'Types' (For example, I had 100 records with Type of "1" that returned 100 unique IDs for each record when its supposed to be 1 NEWID() for all of Type "1", then a new NEWID() for a different type etc etc) and it was catastrophic.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `NEWID()` function.

Comment: You seem to be using SQL-Server, not MySQL. The `UPDATE` syntax is not correct for MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag.  Thanks for the fix.

Comment: `DISTINCT type, NEWID()` won't do what you want. The `NEWID()` will be unique so DISTINCT certainly won't remove anything.


If you want to be certain that `NEWID()` is only evaluated once per `type` materialise it into a temp table anyway. Otherwise you are subject to non deterministic and non guaranteed behaviour w.r.t. where a compute scalar gets evaluated in the execution plan.

Comment: Classic misuse of `DISTINCT` - nearly always using `DISTINCE` implies you're solving the problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your CTE isn't returning distinct IDs. `DISTINCT` applies to the entire `SELECT` list, not just the following column. Since `NEWID()` returns a different ID for each row, you get duplicate types because they have different IDs.

Instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`, use `GROUP BY type` to get one row per type. Use an aggregation function such as `MAX()` or `MIN()` to pick one of the IDs.

```
WITH unique_gen_id AS (
    SELECT type, MAX(NEWID()) AS unique_id
    FROM tmp
    GROUP BY type
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update directly in the CTE with something like:

```
with u as (
    select *
    from t
    cross apply(
        select type, Max(NewId())
        from t t2
        where t2.type = t.type
        group by t2.type
    )n(t,nid)
)
update u set new_id = nid;
```